# Как импортировать модуль из другой папки Python?

Tags: python, django

У меня проблема с подключением подлюля из другой папки, не понимаю, как решить.
Вот так выглядит структура:

```
---- gamers_gazette:
-------- main_app:
------------ models.py
---- utils:
-------- games_parser: 
------------ main.py
```

Как можно импортировать models.py в main.py?
Что бы не пробовал - ничего не работае

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/authoraytee/Documents/Python/gamers-gazette/gamers_gazette/main_app')

from models import Game
```

Полный путь к папке в sys.path.append() помог

Answer (score -1):

**Решение для Python 3.5+:**

```py
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```

Answer (score -2):

По умолчанию вы не можете. При импорте файла Python ищет только текущий каталог, каталог, из которого выполняется точка входа script, и sys.path, который включает в себя такие места, как каталог установки пакета (он на самом деле немного сложнее, чем этот, но это охватывает большинство случаев).

Однако вы можете добавить к пути Python во время выполнения:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: вы, видимо, не дописали свой ответ. нажмите, пожалуйста, [edit], и допишите.